# printk does not register messages in any logs

Tags: linux-kernel

I am using a RiOT ARM, and install an abs minimal Debian 7.5.

I am trying to write an RS485 auto direction driver, and has added some control software. The problem is that the driver is active (because if I do the ioctl command I an either force a pass of fail on command in the driver), but printk messages is nowhere to find.  I checked with

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk (returns 7 4 1 7)
```

and even force

```
echo '8 8 8 8' > /proc/sys/kernel/printk.
```

I also uninstall rsyslog, and re-installed rsyslog, but the strange thing is that I don't have any files in

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/
```

Googling to get an 'default' rsyslog.conf config file seem to be a problem. Strangely I do have dmesg, messages, kern.log, auth etc in /var/log, and these files actually updates

I already tried  KERN_ALERT  (etc) instead of KERN_INFO

The main boot-up console also have no sign of the debug messages

Comment: What do you mean by "these files actually updates"? If the "dmesg" command shows your printk messages, what is missing from the logs?